# ¿Cómo representarías fmts del siguiente código de manera compacta?

Tags: python, random

Este mes he estado trabajando con el módulo random y quiero aprender todo lo que sea necesario hasta dominarlo correctamente. Así que estoy tratando de hacer una lista donde se impriman valores aleatorios con operadores matemáticos, quiero hacer que el programa pueda evaluar la lista que está en el código, y con los símbolos `×`, `·` y `()` pueda aplicar la operación de multiplicación, pero que al mismo tiempo me arroje de manera estética la operación y el resultado. Sé que python no puede evaluar como operador aritmético los caracteres anteriores que mencioné
Trato de hacer esto:

```
1.- (2)(3)
2.- (-4)12
4.- -2(3)
5.- 2*3
6.- 18·12
7.- 1×2
```

Y evitar que ocurra esto:

```
1.- (2)*(3)
2.- (-4)*12
4.- -2×(3)
5.- (2)-3
```

Mi código:

```
from random import randint,choice

archivo=open('EjsPapu.txt', 'w')
insert=int(input('Valor: '))
fmts = (
    '({})({})',
    '-({})({})',
    '({})(-{})',
    '-({})(-{})',
    '(-{})(-{})',
    '-(-{})(-{})',
    '({})({})',
    '-({})({})',
    '({})(-{})',
    '-({})(-{})',
    '(-{})(-{})',
    '-(-{})(-{})',
    '{}({})',
    '-{}({})',
    '{}(-{})',
    '-{}(-{})',
    '({}){}',
    '-({}){}',
    '({}){}',
    '-(-{}){}',
    

    '{} * {}',
    '-{} * {}',
    '{} * -{}',
    '-{} * -{}',
    '-{} * -{}',

    '{} × {}',
    '-{} × {}',
    '{} × -{}',
    '-{} × -{}',
    '-{} × -{}',

    '{} · {}',
    '-{} · {}',
    '{} · -{}',
    '-{} · -{}',
    '-{} · -{}',

 )

result=[]
for i in range(insert):
    x,y = randint(1,30), randint(1,30)
    expr = choice(fmts).format(x,y)
    print(f"={expr}")
    archivo.write(f'{expr} =\n\n')
```

Por cierto, si existe alguna forma de optimizar el código cumpliendo los criterios que quiero que haga, se los agradecería mucho. Saludos.

Comment: Me temo que a partir del ejemplo de lo que quieres que salga y de lo que quieres evitar no soy capaz a adivinar tus especificaciones. ¿De qué se trata exactamente? ¿Eliminar el asterisco cuando se trata de una multiplicación y aparecen paréntesis? ¿Eliminar paréntesis redundantes? ¿Podrías especificar las reglas en vez de (o además de) un ejemplo?

Comment: @abulafia Te ofrezco una disculpa por no explicar bien mi duda. Acabo de actualizar el código, échale un vistazo. Quiero hacer que el programa pueda evaluar la lista que está en el código, y con los símbolos `×`,  `·` y `()` pueda aplicar la operación de multiplicación, pero que al mismo tiempo me arroje de manera estética la operación y el resultado. Sé que python no puede evaluar como operador aritmético los caracteres anteriores que mencioné y no sé cómo resolverlo, por eso planteo mi inquietud. Saludos

Comment: Aunque no entiendo la lógica, a tú código no le sobra nada. Es destacable el enfoque de trabajar con una lista de formatos en lugar de una interminable serie de `if`. La única mejora sería encontrar una manera más compacta de representar `fmts`.

Comment: @CandidMoe, ¿Cómo representarías `fmts` de manera compacta?

Comment: Editas tu pregunta para pedir "¿Cómo representarías fmts de manera compacta? ". Asi podre responderte apropiadamente

Comment: Listo amigo, ya la edité

Comment: Aunque no acabo de entender aún lo que se pretende, tengo una intución de por dónde van los tiros. Si no estoy equivocado seguramente te vendría bien tener "parejas" de formatos. En cada pareja un formato sería el que se usaría para mostrar la ecuación "estéticamente" y el otro formato el que se usaría "internamente" para generar una cadena que le puedas pasar al `eval() `  de python para que te la evalúe. Si crees que los tiros van por aqui, puedo escribir una respuesta

Comment: @abulafia exactamente estoy haciendo eso, declarar una variable y evaluarla llamando a las listas con un string. Algo así: `eval(str(eloperador))`, pero en este caso tomando en cuenta los caracteres anteriormente mencionados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo entender que de lo que trata la pregunta es de generar aleatoriamente una cualquiera de las expresiones que representan una multiplicación de números, en la que la expresión puede usar indistintamente el signo `·` o el signo `×` o ninguno de estos dos símbolos, sino los números encerrados entre paréntesis, y en la que además cualquiera de los números (o ambos) pueden llevar un signo -.  Por ejemplo expresiones válidas de salida podrían ser:

```
13 × 19        
29 · 2         
(30)(17)       
(17)(17)       
(17)13         
(1)(15)        
(18)(2)        
-15 × -13      
-(24)10        
-27 · 13
```

Además de mostrar estas expresiones, se quieren *evaluar*, y aquí viene la parte difícil, ya que para usar el comando `eval()` la expresión debe simplificarse y usar el signo `*` para la multiplicación, por lo que las expresiones dantes dadas deberían dejarse en:

```
13*19
29*2
30*17
17*17
etc...
```

para poder pasárselas a `eval()`

### Posible enfoque

Mi idea, que enuncié en un comentario, es mantener dos cadenas de formato diferentes:

- Una que usa sólo el signo `*` y que se le pasaría a `eval()`
- Otra que usa ya toda la complicación que se quiera usar para producir una salida "estética" como las mostradas anteriormente

Ambas cadenas estarían relacionadas entre sí a través de, por ejemplo, un diccionario. En el diccionario que propongo las claves serían las cadenas para `eval()`, que solo pueden tomar un par de formas, y los valores asociados a cada clave serían listas con todas las formas posibles de mostrar esa operación de forma "estética". Es decir:

```
operaciones = {
    '{}*{}': ['{} × {}', '-{} × -{}', 
              '{} · {}', '-{} · -{}',
              '({})({})', '{}({})', '({}){}', '(-{})(-{})', '-{}(-{})',
              '-(-{})({})', '-(-{}){}'
              ],
    '-{}*{}': ['-{} × {}', '{} × -{}',
               '-{} · {}', '{} · -{}',
               '-({})({})', '({})(-{})', '(-{})({})', '-({}){}', '(-{}){}'
              ]
}
```

Vemos que en realidad, en estos casos, la operación para Python será simplemente multiplicar dos números, o bien multiplicarlos y cambiar el signo del resultado. Para cada uno de estos dos casos hay un buen montón de operaciones que podrían dar ese resultado, según se use `×`, `·` o paréntesis para expresar el producto, y según los signos de los operandos.

A partir de este diccionario podemos generar uno "inverso" en el que las claves serían todas las posibles expresiones "estéticas", y los valores serían la fórmula para `eval()` que computaría el resultado. Este diccionario inverso puede generarse automáticamente:

```
fmts = { formato: operacion for operacion,formatos in operaciones.items() 
                  for formato in formatos }
```

El resultado sería (muestro sólo parte):

```
{'(-{})(-{})': '{}*{}',
 '(-{})({})': '-{}*{}',
 '(-{}){}': '-{}*{}',
 '({})(-{})': '-{}*{}',
 '({})({})': '{}*{}',
 '({}){}': '{}*{}',
 ...
}
```

Ahora podemos usar este diccionario para elegir al azar una cualquiera de sus claves, que sería la expresión a mostrar, y de esa clave obtener la fórmula que la computa, y usar `eval()` para evaluar esa fórmula.

Por ejemplo:

```
from random import randint, choice
result=[]
for i in range(10):
    x,y = randint(1,30), randint(1,30)
    fmt = choice(list(fmts))
    formula = fmts[fmt]
    expr = fmt.format(x,y)
    value = eval(formula.format(x,y))

    print(f"{expr:15} = {value}")
```

Un caso de muestra al ejecutar este bucle produciría:

```
(25)(-4)        = -100
(19)19          = 361
4(23)           = 92
-(-2)7          = 14
11 · 21         = 231
7(26)           = 182
-(-13)1         = 13
16(2)           = 32
24 × 9          = 216
(-10)21         = -210
```

Answer (score 1):

Nota: No he logrado entender la lógica detrás de la pregunta. Sin embargo, abordandolo como un problema de refactorización puede convertir el código para lograr una representación más compacta de los datos.

Será el mismo resultado obtenido de otra forma. La ventaja es que no necesito crear una tabla de combinaciones explicita, que podría estar incompleta o incorrecta.

**Análisis**

`ftms` guarda los formatos aceptables. Esta lista muestra todas las posibles combinaciones de la expresión aritmética

```
a operador b
```

Donde `a` y `b` son valores positivos/negativos con/sin paréntesis.

**Primera reducción**

Como `a` y `b` son intercambiables, no necesito explicitar todas las combinaciones; basta con que liste las variaciones permitidas para un operando. Por ejemplo, estas líneas, mostrando combinaciones de `a` y `b`:

```
   '({})({})',
    '-({})({})',
    '({})(-{})',
    '-({})(-{})',
    '(-{})(-{})',
    '-(-{})(-{})',
    '({})({})',
```

Se pueden reducir a esta otra:

```
   '({})',
    '-({})',
    '-(-{})',
```

Que nos dice que un operando va entre paréntesis y puede llevar un signo menos por delante. Como `a` y `b` se rigen por las mismas reglas, significa que todas las combinaciones generadas son válidas.

**Segunda reducción**

Todas las operaciones válida son de la forma

```
a operador b
```

donde operador sale de la lista `['', '+', '-', '*', '/', '.']` (Al parecer se considera válido no tener operador)

Por tanto, puedo olvidarme de los formatos como, que se repiten para cada operador

```
'{} × {}',
'-{} × {}',
'{} × -{}',
'-{} × -{}',
'-{} × -{}',
```

y reemplazarlos con una única línea que diga

```
`{} op {}`
```

donde `{}` representa el valor generado `a` y `b`.  Como `a` y `b` ya vienen con posibles signos menos unitarios, sería incorrecto usarlo en la fórmula generadora.

**Aplicación**

Habiendo reducido el tamaño de `fmts`, ahora puedo eliminarlo por completo y usar simplemente código que represente esa información

```
import random

def gen_valor():
    valor = random.randint(-10,10)
    formato = random.randint(0, 3)
    if formato == 0:
        return valor
    elif formato == 1:
        return f"({valor})"

    return f"-({valor})"

def gen_operacion():
    a = gen_valor()
    b = gen_valor()
    idx = random.randint(0, 5)
    operador = ['', '+', '-', '*', '/', '.'][idx]
    return f"{a} {operador} {b}"

for i in range(10):
    print(gen_operacion())
```

produce:

```
-(-4) - -(6)
(0)  -(-5)
-(-5) . (-4)
(-9) / (6)
(10) + -2
-(-1) * (-2)
(-9) / -(-1)
-(2) + 6
-(3) - -(-5)
-3 * -7
```

Comment: Aunque la idea de generar algorítmicamente los formatos válidos es muy interesante, la implementación no es tan sencilla, me temo. Por ejemplo la ausencia de operador se interpreta como producto en expresiones como `3(-2)`, que daría -6, pero si no estuvieran los paréntesis la expresión sería `3 -2`, que ya no se evaluaría como producto, sino como resta. Esta expresión (entiendo yo) no debería generarse. Y como éste hay más casos a exceptuar. Yo no encontré aún una forma sencilla de generar sólo formatos válidos si no es usando algún tipo de gramática.

Comment: @abulafia. El problema está en permitir expresiones sin operador. Eso no pasa en ningun lenguaje de programación.

Comment: Yo entiendo (pero estoy solo adivinando) que pretende hacer una especie de "generador de ejercicios" para estudiantes de aritmética elemental. Quiere presentarles a esos estudiantes una serie de expresiones y sus resultados. Las expresiones quiere escribirlas usando notación matemática válida, y en ésta sí que es posible omitir el signo de multiplicar en expresiones con paréntesis como (2)(3), o 3(5). Pero a la vez quiere que python pueda evaluar la expresión para darle el resultado al estudiante.

Comment: @abulafia Enseñar a omitir el operador "*" va a contrapelo del siglo XXI.

Comment: @abulafia Has dado en el clavo, estoy haciendo libros para ayudar a alumnos de prepa a pasar la PAA (College Board) y dentro del primer capítulo, están los subtemas indispensables de dominar al derecho y al revés las multiplicaciones. Los demás temas los tendré que generar de manera casi manual. Saludos!

Comment: @CandidMoe, de nuevo me has ayudado muchísimo en hacer de manera más óptima el código, me parece excelente cómo lo has desarrollado. De alguna manera le voy a encontrar un uso e implementarlo; quiero ser honesto, me costó trabajo procesarlo y digerirlo, pero ya lo entendí. Muchas gracias amigo!