# Resolver jerarquía de operaciones con python

Tags: python, math, replace

Soy muy principiante en programación y por eso necesito ayuda con mi primer tarea en Python:
Tengo una expresión matemática que puede ser algo como esto: `{{(75-1)4}/2]+(6-2){21+2}` y necesito resolverla correctamente.
Primero con `replace` cambio las llaves y corchete por paréntesis:

```
expression = '{{(75-1)4}/2]+(6-2){21+2}'
print(expression.replace("{",'(').replace("[","(").replace("}",")").replace("]",")"))
```

Me retorna algo como esto: `(((75-1)4)/2)+(6-2)(21+2)`, pero ahora necesito resolver esta jerarquía de operaciones.

El problema es que no puedo usar la función `eval` para obtener el resultado.
Necesito de alguna forma  extraer las ecuaciones e irlas resolviendo por partes.

Intenté simplemente castear a `int` la expresion, esperando que me diera el resultado luego de cambiar todo a paréntesis, pero no pude.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lo que estas pidiendo es un analizar lexico que te permita ir partiendo la ecuacion por partes y luego ir haciendo cada una de las partes.. no es algo simple.. y tampoco es algo que te vayan a dar en una respuesta, porque aca no resolvemos ejercicios.

Comment: Buena suerte haciendo un analizador sintáctico y estableciendo prioridad de operaciones :D

Comment: El requerimiento excede las capacidades de un principiante. Cómo mínimo necesitas saber recursividad.

Comment: Para esto tienes que saber hacer un intérprete y un analizador sintáctico, creo que deberías aprender otras cosas antes..

Comment: Me costó casi tres semanas resolver este problema en mis tiempos libres, pero en mi caso era al revés, primero imprimía sintácticamente y luego estéticamente, básicamente @Abufalia me ayudó con el intérprete y tuve que añadir el analizador sintáctico. Si te pasas por mis preguntas verás como inicié más o menos como tú y fui aprendiendo más o menos a programar preguntando cosas.

Comment: Pásate por esta pregunta y dale un vistazo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426023/c%c3%b3mo-representar%c3%adas-fmts-del-siguiente-c%c3%b3digo-de-manera-compacta

Answer (score 2):

La opción de **eval(exp)** es la correcta, pero date cuenta de que la expresión **'(((75-1)4)/2)+(6-2)(21+2)'** está mal formada, debe ser así **'(((75-1)*4)/2)+(6-2)*(21+2)'**. Nota los asteriscos para expresar una multiplicación. Añade un par de "replace" más, para este caso, el primero deberías sustituir **')4'** por **')*4'** y el siguiente **')('** por **')*('**. En el caso del cierre de paréntesis seguido de un número para una regla que sirva para más casos, deberías mirar una expresión regular que sirva para cualquier dígito. Sigue por ese camino y podrás evaluar cualquier expresión asegurándote que esté bien formada.
Espero que te ayude, un saludo.

Comment: Usar `eval` no es tan bueno

Comment: He leído en stackoverflow en inglés lo mismo que comentas, que usar `eval` no es una buena práctica, ¿por qué no?

Comment: De hecho ya tenía la respuesta para esta misma pregunta, pero cuando leí que no se puede usar `eval`, intenté resolver la operación con `sympy`, pero no me funcionó, hubiera sido más simple utilizar `eval()`, pero no pude sustituirla por otra función. Fue algo muy similar a lo que vimos ayer de las ecuaciones al crear las expresiones regulares

Comment: Este sería el código, lo pongo como comentario porque en la pregunta piden que el códigno no tenga `eval()` https://pastebin.com/zxPiPYUt

Answer (score 0):

```
def calcular_subexpresion(subexpresion):
    resultado = subexpresion[0]
    for i in range(1, len(subexpresion), 2):
        operador = subexpresion[i]
        operando = subexpresion[i+1]
        if operador == '+':
            resultado += operando
        elif operador == '-':
            resultado -= operando
        elif operador == '*':
            resultado *= operando
        elif operador == '/':
            resultado /= operando
    return resultado

expresion = input("Ingrese una expresión matemática: ")
new_expression = expresion.replace("{", "(").replace("[", "(").replace("}", ")").replace("]", ")")
print(f"La expresión {expresion} es equivalente a {new_expression}")
subexpresion = []
for c in new_expression:
    if c.isdigit():
        if subexpresion and isinstance(subexpresion[-1], int):
            subexpresion[-1] = subexpresion[-1] * 10 + int(c)
        else:
            subexpresion.append(int(c))
    elif c in '+-*/':
        subexpresion.append(c)

resultado = calcular_subexpresion(subexpresion)

print(f"El resultado de la expresión es {resultado}")
```

Primero, el usuario ingresa la expresión matemática y esta se guarda en la variable `expresion`. Luego, se crea una nueva expresión llamada `new_expression` que es una versión equivalente de la expresión original pero con los corchetes y llaves reemplazados por paréntesis.

A continuación, se define una función llamada `calcular_subexpresion` que recibe una lista de números y operadores y calcula el resultado de esa `subexpresión`. La función itera a través de la `subexpresión`, operando en cada operador con sus correspondientes operandos.

Después, se crea una lista llamada `subexpresion` que se llenará con los números y operadores de la expresión. La lista `subexpresion` se crea a partir de la `new_expression` creada anteriormente. Si un carácter es un número, se agrega a la lista como un entero. Si el carácter es un operador, se agrega a la lista como un carácter.

Finalmente, la función `calcular_subexpresion` se llama con la `subexpresion` como argumento para calcular el resultado de la expresión matemática. El resultado se almacena en la variable resultado y se imprime en la consola.

Cabe destacar que este código solo es capaz de manejar expresiones matemáticas simples que no contengan variables, funciones u otras operaciones más complejas.